# Producer consumer pattern in JAVA

Tags: java, producer-consumer

[Here the pattern of consumer-producer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Rkz.png)

`Producer` creates a new message, `consumer` listens for them via `Broker`.

So far, `producer` creates and sends a message while `consumer` waits for message. When new message comes `consumer` prints it to the screen.

I want `Producer` to be informed that `Consumer` has received the message and dequeued it.

I wonder is there any way to notify/feedack `Producer` from `Consumer`? Or should I inform `Consumer` via `Broker`? How can do it?

Comment: There is no simple yes/no answer here. You figured it yourself, there are many options to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JMS standard supports a Reply Queue (JMSReplyTo), so that the original consumer can return a reply message to the original producer on the specific queue.

As shown here;

http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReplyJmsExample.html

[image]

If you also use the JMSCorrelationID, then you can link the messages together, so that you know the reply relates to the specific request with id xxxxx.

Of coruse this then means the the consumer will become a producer for the reply message.

The link provided also has code to show a working example (although I have not tried it myself)

Comment: Good answer, but the queue need not be JMS.  It could be an in-memory blocking deque.

Comment: True.  I made an assumption based on lack of details in the question.

Comment: Still a fine, correct answer by you.  Shows a great understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd ask why the Producer needs to know.

The whole purpose of producer/consumer is to decouple the two objects.  Producers don't know or care who handles the message.

Your proposal breaks that model.  You should not do so unless you have a very good reason besides "I want to."

If you must, give the consumer class a reference to the producer and expose a method on it that can be used to send the message.  Or couple them in a database by having the consumer write to a table that the producer can also query.

But now the two are hopelessly entangled.  I think it's a bad choice.

Comment: You could add a ACK system link to the Queue. Just to know that the message has been processed (but if there is no more message, you already know...) but not from who. This is less problematic

Comment: What if it's not a JMS queue?  Could be an in-memory BlockingDeque.  Still a bad idea.

Comment: I agree, from the beginning this is a bad idea. I would not use this design if I need to know if the message is processed at anytime. I was not talking about a JMS Queue specificly, any sort of Set could do it actually. I am thinking like a TCP communication but without answering directly to the Producer. Using a separate Collection that the Producer could check **if needed**. But again, why, when, how, to many question to be a good idea ;)

Comment: @duffymo I think there are various ways where one side wants to "drop" some package for processing and doesn't really care who/what will work on it - but needs some kind of feedback that processing happened. So given the fact that many such "flow" systems do consider such behavior ... there seems to be some need for it. Like http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.2/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html ... or am I mistaken here?

Comment: @GhostCat, I think you and jason.kaisersmith are correct.  Decoupling is also a good idea.  Depends on the use case.

Comment: @duffymo Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

It's more like *Listener* pattern. Use `EventBus`. 2 events: `public PutEvent(MyType message) {...}`, `public TakeEvent(long id) {...}`. Then:

```
EventBus bus = new SimpleEventBus();
bus.addHandler(producerInstance::onMessageTaken, GetEvent.getType());
bus.addHandler(consumerInstance::onMessageArrived, PutEvent.getType());
```

Consumer:

```
MyType message = queue.pop();
bus.fireEventFromSource(new TakeEvent(message.getId()), this);
...
@Override public void onMessageArrived(PutEvent event) {
  // We know, that there're messages out there and can later pop it
  System.out.printf("%d from %s", event.getMessage().getId(), event.getSource() != null ? event.getSource().hashCode() + "" : "unknown");
}
```

Producer:

```
MyType message = new MyType(data, ++id);
queue.add(message);
bus.fireEventFromSource(new PutEvent(message), this);
...
@Override public void onMessageTaken(TakeEvent event) {
  // Wow, who took it?
  System.out.printf("%s took %d", event.getSource() != null ? event.getSource().hashCode() + "" : "unknown", event.getId());
}
```